# How to validate HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE?

Tags: php

Since the script gets `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` from the visitor it could be anything. So how can I validate it? What is acceptable?

To get the first language inside the string I use:

`substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"],0,2)`

Comment: [Here is the w3 spec on `Accept-Language`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4)

Comment: The `Locale` class has [some methods for dealing with Accept-Language](http://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.acceptfromhttp.php). I'd probably go with that rather than attempting to build something myself (part of the intl extension).

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Of course I should! Stupid me.

Comment: Define "validate". What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: I just wanted to check if all characters are acceptable chars. To prevent XSS etc.

Answer (score 1):

*For example*

```
$user_lang= split(",",$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]);
$language = $user_lang[0];

// header injection.
if(stripos($language, 'Content-Type') !== FALSE ) { exit; }
```